# Selecting the very last record of the returned table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm from an access background with a little mySQL, so I'm slightly lost when it comes to SQL.

Here is the query I am using:

```
Select 
    tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.NTlogin,
    tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Firstname,
    tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Lastname,
    tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.CaseId,
    tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.ContactNumber,
    CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_PRICE,
    CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_CREATEDDATE
```

This returns the proper record, but I want the very last... I know I should use something like this...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM table_Name 
ORDER BY unique_column DESC
```

Where I get lost, and if I am correct in saying so, you can only do one Select... so how do I integrate the two? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps add some example data?  Is there more than one table?

Comment: What is your question?  Your example has only one "select" in it.  You can use the "top" clause with any select query, regardless of the number of tables in the "from" clause.

Comment: You have to show how these tables are linked. What are the foreign-keys? Then you can use a join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are wanting is something like:

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.NTlogin,
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Firstname,
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Lastname,
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.CaseId,
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.ContactNumber,
  CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_PRICE,
  CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_CREATEDDATE
FROM
  tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR
JOIN CRM_TRN_ORDER
    ON tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.CustomerId = CRM_TRN_ORDER.CUSTOMERID
ORDER BY
  CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_CREATEDDATE DESC
```

Note: I made up the JOIN clause, because I don't know your schema.  You should pick real columns that satisfy the join, assuming there is a foreign key relationship of some kind.  Otherwise, you would simply be taking a cartesian product which is most likely NOT what you want.  However, you could do that by replacing the FROM ... JOIN clauses above with      "FROM tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR, CRM_TRN_ORDER".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
Select TOP (1)
tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.NTlogin,
tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Firstname,
tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.Customer_Lastname,
tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.CaseId,
tbl_AcerPFSSurveyIVR.ContactNumber,
CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_PRICE,
CRM_TRN_ORDER.ORDER_CREATEDDATE 
FROM Table_Name ORDER BY unique_Column DESC
```

This Includes a top 1 in your previous query and filters the request by descending order at the same time. I took for granted that the first `SELECT`was from `table_name`.

Comment: The "FROM Table_Name ORDER BY unique_Column DESC" the poster used above was just an example.  I don't think they meant to merge the two into one SQL statement.